Displaying YouTube playlist scrollbar when webpage loads
I have embedded a YouTube playlist on my very basic HTML webpage. When i load the webpage it appears like this, as expected it shows the first video in playlist and if you want to see the rest you click the icon in the top right corner of the frame.
(https://i.sstatic.net/xJ7Fy2iI.png)
I wonder if it is possible to have the scrollbar with the full list of videos appear upon loading the page. As it looks in this second screenshot.
(https://i.sstatic.net/Jfc40EQ2.png)
It is a very basic website for some internet art related things. The focus of the embed is the playlist itself and not necessarily viewing the playlist from beginning to end, which is why I want the list to appear upon loading.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. It doesn't seem like I can have it display the way I'd like by changing iFrame parameters, perhaps there is another workaround?
I've looked over the different iFrame parameters that can be changed but don't see any that have to do with displaying the playlist and it's scrollbar.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
